# Android resource practices for libraries

Tags: android, formatting, android-library

It is already well established that `dimensions`, `colors`, and other resource related values should be stored in their respective XML file.  However, is this still appropriate when creating a library?  Defining these resources in a library's XML file would perhaps bring confusion to anyone using the library.  Are there are recommended practices for defining resources in a library project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes one giant one .. prefix the resource name both in the id and the xmlfile name as resources with same names often clash with parent stuff that has the same name

Comment: What's the need for prefixing the xml file name?